# How to close help buffer without moving to it?

Tags: window, help, focus, selected-window

I often use Emacs' help buffers, via e.g. `C-h k`.

Buffer `*Help*` is displayed in another window, and that window is not selected. In order to close the `*Help*` buffer, I need to switch windows via `C-x o` and then press `q` to close the `*Help*` buffer.

The solution of always opening the `*Help*` buffer in the current window, described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22499/how-can-i-tell-emacs-to-always-open-help-buffers-in-the-current-window), almost works. But I would rather open the help in a different window.

Is it possible to close the `*Help*` buffer without moving to it, or to set it so that the cursor appears in the help buffer (which would mean I would just need to type `q` to exit)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can automatically have the `*Help*` window be selected when it is displayed, by customizing option **`help-window-select`**.

> **`help-window-select`** is a variable defined in `help.el`.
>   Its value is `t`
>
> Original value was `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means select help window for viewing.
>
> Choices are:
>
> - never (`nil`) -- Select help window only if there is no other window on its frame.
> - other --      Select help window if and only if it appears on the
>              previously selected frame, that frame contains at
>              least two other windows and the help window is
>              either new or showed a different buffer before.
> - always (`t`) -- Always select the help window.
>
> If this option is non-`nil` and the help window appears on another
>   frame, then give that frame input focus too.  Note also that if
>   the help window appears on another frame, it may get selected and
>   its frame get input focus even if this option is `nil`.
>
> This option has effect if and only if the help window was created
>   by `with-help-window`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to close the *Help* buffer without moving to it

Yes.  There's more than one option, but I recommend the following:

- Add `(winner-mode 1)` to your init file.
- Type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> to call `winner-undo` to get rid of the *Help* buffer after it pops up.

What this actually does is *restore the previous window configuration* and it is a more powerful tool than merely something for dismissing unwanted pop-ups, but it's really handy for doing that too.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Window Convenience` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an elisp function for this.
It cycles through all windows and closes/restores the one that contains
a buffer named *Help*

```
(defun reset-help-window ()
  "Restore help window to previous state"
  (let ((help-window nil) (windows (window-list)))
    (dotimes (i (length (window-list)))
      (when (equal (buffer-name) "*Help*")
    (setf help-window (nth i windows)))
      (other-window 1))
    (if help-window
    (quit-restore-window help-window)
      (print "No Help window"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I stole from `scroll-other-window` to find the window to close.
This works well for me!

**EDIT**: as @NickD points out, works-for-me is only when there was a single window before help was invoked. @Nselm's function works for any number of window splits

`quit-window` will call `quit-restore-window`

```
(defun my/quit-other ()                                                                                                                              
  "quit e.g. *HELP* buffer without switching to it."                                                                                                                          
  (interactive)
  (with-selected-window (other-window-for-scrolling) (quit-window)))
```

Elsewhere, I've bound <kbd>SPACE q</kbd> to close the other window without having to first do <kbd>C-x o</kbd>.

```
(evil-leader/set-key "q" #'my/quit-other)
```

Comment: That works if you have a single window when you open the `*Help*` buffer, but it won't necessarily work if you have more than one window: it might or it might not - you can't be sure that `(other-window-for-scrolling)` will give you the one with the `*Help*` buffer.

Comment: @NickD thanks for pointing that out! I'd thought `(other-window-for-scroling)` was smarter about what window was most recently changed

Answer (score 0):

FYI you did say 'close' but if you had multiple windows open visiting multiple buffers and the `*Help*` (or `*Arpopos*` or `*Occur*` or...) buffer opened in window over another buffer you want back, then `switch-to-buffer-other-window` does that. It defaults to the previous buffer in that window. Or `M-p` can cycle through other previous buffers.

`switch-to-buffer-other-window` is by default bound to `C-x 4 b`

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212426/how-do-i-close-an-automatically-opened-window-in-emacs/