# How to automatically select apropos buffer when it is displayed

Tags: help, focus, selected-window, apropos

It is possible to automatically select `*Help*` buffers when they are displayed by doing `(setq help-window-select t)` (relevant question: [How to close help buffer without moving to it?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58717/how-to-close-help-buffer-without-moving-to-it)).

Is there a similar setting for `*Apropos*` buffers? When I use apropos using `C-h a`, the resulting apropos buffer is not automatically selected. I have to switch to it using `C-x o`. Is there a way to switch to the apropos buffer automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function to `apropos-mode-hook` that selects the window for the Apropos buffer.

```lisp
(defun my-apropos-select-window ()
  "..."
  (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer)))

(add-hook 'apropos-mode-hook #'my-apropos-select-window)
```

Comment: The next release of Emacs (the one right after Emacs 28.1) will use the value of `help-window-select` to control this behavior. Relevant commits: [Make `M-x apropos' respect help-window-select](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=4ea8ab77e295fc508fc910e8278540ebcce293fb) (2022-04-30) and [Document 'help-window-select'](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=a3024ab4fb6b608d2110aa778c1eadec8113f498) (2022-05-01).

Comment: @Flux: I think your comment belongs on the question, not on this answer. Or maybe you can post it as another answer.